# Copying the serialization class between two servers

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm building a system with two servers and I'm building an API interface between them. The one is a normal Django web server and the other is a calculation server (also Django powered) which performs complex calculations from specific inputs. I've split the website and the calculation server to decouple the components.

I'm using the Django rest framework and I've created a serialization class on the webserver. This is for the inputs that gets sent to the calculation server and is populated from various DB entries. I then pass the serialized data as parameters in a get request to the calc server. I then copy that same serialization class to the calculation server to de-serialize/decode the data and perform the calculation.

**Is it normal to use this approach, where I'm copying the serialization class between the two servers?** Usually when I copy something I'm doing it wrong.

The calculated results are then just returned to my web server using built-in python and django functions. I don't see a need for the django rest framework during this step.

Comment: Are you talking about copying code? If so why don't you use the same django-app on webserver and calcualtion server?

Comment: Didn't consider that, but I'll give it a go. Thanks!